How to correct compose sampler in JMeter
I would like to define a plan test with JMeter to evaluate the composition of two different services and analyse how they respond in presence of concurrent threads. However, the results obtained are different from those expected.
For example, let's say we have a sampler1 whose average response time is 6ms with only one thread (N=1). By increasing the number of threads to N=10 I observe the response time increase to about 60ms. Furthermore, let us assume we have a sampler2 whose average response time is 12ms with N=1. When N=10, we get about 120ms.
Now, if we try to compose sampler1 and sampler2 in sequence, I expect that for N=1, the average response time will be 6+12=18ms. While for N=10, the average response time will be 60+120=180ms. Instead, in the latter case I get that the fastest service (i.e. sampler1) continues to behave like the non-concurrent case (i.e. about 6ms) while only the slowest service is affected by the concurrency.
I leave below the configuration used. To do this experiment, I implemented a Servlet that calculates the first n natural numbers (sampler1 requires n=10000000, while sampler2 requires n=20000000). These services are hosted on WildFly and deployed with Docker by exposing them to unique ports and allocating dedicated resources to make them independent.
@WebServlet("/service/sum")
public class SumServiceServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        String paramN = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("n"));

        // Calculate the sum of the first n natural numbers.
        long sum = 0;
        for (long i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            sum += i;
        }

        // Return the result.
        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.getWriter().write(
            "Sum of the first " + n + " natural numbers: " + sum
        );
    }
}

services:
  service_1:
    image: jboss/wildfly:latest
    container_name: service_1
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    cpuset: '0'
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '1'
          memory: '1024M'
    volumes:
      - ./target/ROOT.war:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war
  
  service_2:
    image: jboss/wildfly:latest
    container_name: service_2
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    cpuset: '1'
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '1'
          memory: '1024M'
    volumes:
      - ./target/ROOT.war:/opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/ROOT.war

How can I correctly simulate the problem with JMeter and achieve the expected results (i.e. what can be the configuration of JMeter to solve this problem). I have also tried limiting the input troughput to avoid queues forming on the slower service, but I cannot find a correct configuration to achieve the expected results.

JMeter will wait for response from the previous request before sending the next request, it means that if you place 2 HTTP Request samplers into a single Thread Group - both requests will be executed with the throughput of the slowest API endpoint throughput.
The solution would be placing these HTTP Request samplers in different Thread Groups.

Also regarding your approach using Docker - it is not something you should be normally doing as you won't be able to extrapolate your performance test results, you should be running load tests against a production environment or its replica (unless you're doing some form of a scalability test)

Docker is necessary to simulate the problem that I have to analyze and distribute services independently. However, in this configuration would it happen that N requests are executed on thread group 1 and then on thread group 2 (the users are not necessarily the same)? Also, if I wanted to analyse the case of parallel instead of sequential composition, how could this configuration be solved?
